# How to make Pool sensitive of KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Is there a way to manually get out of a multithreaded operation? Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
pool = Pool(num_parallel_workers)
pool.map(update_completions_in_parallel, list_of_hits)
# press ctrl+c in middle of operation to 'exit' and return to CLI prompt
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use an iterated or asynchronous map?  These are easy to interrupt or kill or whatever as the map is not blocking.

See a good usage example here:
[Python multiprocessing - tracking the process of pool.map operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375508/python-multiprocessing-tracking-the-process-of-pool-map-operation/28382913#28382913)

I used `pathos` for my answer linked above, but there are also `imap` and `map_async` available from plain old `multiprocessing`.

```
>>> import multiprocessing as mp
>>> p = mp.Pool()   
>>> p.imap
<bound method Pool.imap of <multiprocessing.pool.Pool object at 0x109592c50>>
>>> p.map_async 
<bound method Pool.map_async of <multiprocessing.pool.Pool object at 0x109592c50>>
```

However, if you are looking to terminate the processes/threads that were launched already by doing a `close` then `join`… and then save cycles… what you typed (i.e. `close` then `join`) is not going to work.  You have to use `terminate` to do that… and terminating a `pool` is not recommended if you plan on touching the pool or result object afterward.  Better to use an iterated/asynchronous map, then when see you have what you want -- just *ignore* the rest and move on.