# how to use python's multiprocessing module

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm using Intel's Pentium(R)Dual-core E5700 @3.00GHz with 2GB ram.
I'm trying to learn Python's `multiprocessing` module. I wrote a simple program that perfoms addition, but its not working; I'm only a getting number of core 2. Is something wrong with my pc or my code?

```
import multiprocessing
print "number of core ",multiprocessing.cpu_count()



def calc(a,b):
    c= a+b
    return c

if __name__ =='__main__':

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=calc,args=(3,5) )
    p1.start()
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=calc,args=(2,2) )
    p2.start()



p1.join()
p2.join()
```

Comment: change `return c` to `print c`

Comment: why changed return to print ,it is function its work perfectly when i call it  calc(2,3) im getting 5

Comment: If you have a dual-core machine, then your CPU count is two. What makes you think this is wrong? What are you expecting it to be?

Comment: k..then how you know the function is executed by your prgm? Also You getting `number of core 2`. Then what is the problem facing in your program?

Comment: It's not clear from your question what part of the program isn't working. What behavior are you seeing? What behavior are you expecting to see?

Comment: @ lost-theory i m expecting the result ,do u dont think that i shoud get 8 and 4 as result but im only getting number of core

Comment: He's trying to figure out why is function won't output. The only output he is getting is the number of cores he has. Is that right?

Comment: if you want result not only to print in terminal, refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797998/is-it-possible-to-multiprocesspython-a-function-that-returns-something

Comment: @guiboy No, you won't see 8 and 4 get printed unless you explicitly `print` them. The only thing you print is `"number of core ", multiprocessing.cpu_count()`, so that's all that's going to get printed.

Comment: If I remember correctly, `return` will make it so that the system can use it, but it won't output to the screen. You can use `print` and `return` in the same function, as long as `print` comes before `return` -> Good if you need to see output and make it system usable at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue). Look this example:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process

def calc(a, b, queue):
    queue.put(a + b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = Queue()
    p1 = Process(target = calc, args = (4, 4, queue,))
    p2 = Process(target = calc, args = (4, 4, queue,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    result_1 = queue.get()
    result_2 = queue.get()
    print(result_1, result_2)
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    input()

>>> 8 8
```

The same code dynamically:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process, cpu_count

def calc(a, b, queue):
    queue.put(a + b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = Queue()
    processes = []
    for i in range(cpu_count()):
        processes.append(Process(target = calc, args = (4, 4, queue,)))
        processes[-1].start()
    results = []
    for i in range(cpu_count()):
        results.append(queue.get())
    print(results)
    for process in processes:
        process.join()

>>> [8, 8] # if you have two cores
```

Comment: ur both example sometime its work ,sometime its jam ide like while loop,i think multiprocessing dont work properly on windows

Comment: it works... check if you aren't using IDLE to run the code and, in boot advanced options on msconfig, the configuration is allowing you to use all cores.

Answer (score 1):

everything work perfectly including my calc program under pycharm only problem was IDE,i was using pyscripter

Answer (score 0):

In your `calc` function, you need to change `return` to `print`. On my quad-core machine (running OS X Mavericks), this is my output when running the script in terminal. You should also put `p1.join()` and `p2.join()` as part of your `if __name__ == "__main__`.

```
Last login: Sun Feb 15 15:47:18 on ttys001
imac:~ zinedine$ cd '/Users/zinedine/Documents/' && '/usr/local/bin/pythonw'
'/Users/zinedine/Documents/example.py'  && echo Exit status: $? && exit 1
number of cores  4
8
4
Exit status: 0
logout

[Process completed]
```

The code that I used in Terminal...

```
import multiprocessing

print "number of cores ", multiprocessing.cpu_count()

def calc(a, b):
    c = a + b
    return c

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = calc, args = (3, 5) )
    p1.start()

    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = calc, args = (2, 2) )
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

After using `Python Launcher.app`, It opens in Terminal and it gives the output that I gave above...

Comment: i did still not working 
import multiprocessing
print "number of core ",multiprocessing.cpu_count()



def calc(a,b):
    c= a+b
    print c

if __name__ =='__main__':
  
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=calc,args=(3,5) )
    p1.start()
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=calc,args=(2,2) )
    p2.start()



p1.join()
p2.join()

Comment: Why are you doing `from multiprocessing import Process` and `import multiprocessing`? Just do a simple `import multiprocessing`. But that's besides the point. Do you think you can make an edit to your question describing your output?

Comment: this script can only run as python file.Since processing done under `if __name__ =='__main__':`.So there is no need of indentation for `p1.join()` and `p2.join` .It will execute anyways

Comment: no, i m not doing import multiprocessing , im doing import multiprocessing u can test my code in ur terminal ,sorry im little confuse

Comment: @latheefitzmeontv It's actually a bug to not indent it. On Windows, that code will be executed in each child process, while the code in the `if __name__ ...` block will not. Obviously that is not desirable, since it will make both child processes crash. You'd have the same issue if you were to import the module instead of executing it directly.

Comment: @dano thats correct. If it import, there should be issue.Since he programmed multiprocessing under `if main`. K that is not the issue here ;)

Comment: @latheefitzmeontv If you were to try to run that code on Windows, it would be an issue. Windows need to re-import the `__main__` module in each child process created by the `multiprocessing` module in order to execute `calc`. That import will fail because of the indentation issue, so neither child process will execute properly. Things will work fine on Linux/OSX because they support `fork` and don't need to re-import `__main__` in each child.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Your code will always work, because you indented properly. The OP's code will not work on Windows, because the calls to `join()` are not indented properly.

Comment: So, if the OP indents the `join()`, the code will work on Windows?

Comment: this code sometime work properly ,sometime its jam ide like in while loop ;from multiprocessing import Queue, Process, cpu_count

def calc(a, b, queue):
    queue.put(a + b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = Queue()
    processes = []
    for i in range(cpu_count()):
        processes.append(Process(target = calc, args = (4, 4, queue,)))
        processes[-1].start()
    results = []
    for i in range(cpu_count()):
        results.append(queue.get())
    print(results)
    for process in processes:
        process.join()

Comment: sometimes? Oh, make sure you comment on the right question! :)